# Counting previous values

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image]

I can’t understand why the counter is not working correctly, blue is the value, red is the value plus the previous one, white is the current plus the two previous ones, that’s just the white is not working correctly, please help. Below is the code.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", overlay = true, format=format.price, precision=2)
periodK = input.int(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(3, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = int(ta.sma(k, periodD))
//plot(k, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)
a = 31
plot(a, '1', color.yellow)

bool isCond11 = ta.crossover(d, a)
bool isCond21 = ta.crossunder(d, a) 
bool isCond1 = ta.cross(a, d) 

varip int e = 0
varip int r = 0
var x = 0
var int t = 0
varip float p = 0
varip float p1 = 0
varip float p2 = 0
var NoBars = bar_index
var NbBars = 0

e := isCond11 ? 1 : 0
x := isCond11 ? 1 : isCond21[1] ? 0 : nz(x[1])
r := isCond21 ? 2 : 0

if isCond1
    NbBars := bar_index - NoBars
    NoBars := bar_index
    label.new(bar_index, d, text=str.tostring(NbBars))
    p := NbBars
    p1 := NbBars[1]  + NbBars
    p2 := NbBars + NbBars[1] + NbBars[2]
///    label.new(bar_index, d, text=str.tostring(p))
    label.new(bar_index, d[1], text=str.tostring(p1), color = color.red)
    label.new(bar_index, d[2], text=str.tostring(p2), color = color.white)
```